# Can apollo server return a partial success if one element of an array is invalid?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

Say I have a query that returns an array of Customer objects, each one having an `id`, `name`, and `email`, all of which are non-nullable. My resolver loads the data from some source, maybe a database or maybe a downstream system. Most of the data that comes back is fine, but maybe for some reason we're missing the email address for a single customer.

Currently if my resolver just returns the array of all known customers, including the dodgy one, then the entire operation will fail with something like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "customers": null
  },
  "errors": [{
    "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Customer.email"
    // More error stuff here
  }]
}
```

I get that the validation is supposed to be strict, but now on my UI it fails to load the entire list of customers just because one of them is invalid. It makes it too easy for a single record to poison the entire database.

What I would like is a way to still return the error, but to also have the `data` field be populated with all of the other, valid `Customer` records. Is this possible to do with apollo server? Or do I need to manually validate all of the data before trying to return it from my resolver? That would be quite arduous as my real data structure is much more complex.

Comment: simply make it nullable but still non-nullable on input type (for new records) ? detect nulled e-mail in UI, filter out from lists or display warnings on profile page or force updates on login ... warnings (not errors) can be implemented separately but on field resolver or some additional response validating middleware ... validating DB could be better for [DB] consistency

Comment: Thanks @xadm. I'm trying to avoid making fields nullable as I don't want the frontend to have to do null checks for every field. I'm going to make the Customer object itself nullable so that any records with bad data will come back as null, and the frontend can easily filter them out and ignore them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this discussion](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/discussions/5889#discussioncomment-1624036), it seems there's no way to do exactly what I was asking (filter out the invalid records on the server side).

The right approach to this is to either:

1. Make the `email` field nullable, so the server can return every `Customer`, some of which may have incomplete data; or
2. Make the elements of the top-level `Customer` array nullable, so the server can return e.g. `[customer1, null, customer3]`

Option 1 means that the client gets access to more data on an error, so it could still show the rest of the customer's details even if the email is missing. However it makes the data structure less reliable as now anywhere that uses the email might need to do a null check.

Option 2 is a more aggressive failure, nulling out the entire customer because of a single bad field. But it makes it simpler for the client to filter out bad customer records at the top level, allowing the rest of the frontend code to be confident that every customer has an email address.

On that basis I think I prefer option 2.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in this article: https://blog.logrocket.com/handling-graphql-errors-like-a-champ-with-unions-and-interfaces/

It talks about using union types to report result status rather than  traditional GQL error reporting.  Here's an example of how it might look in your case:

```
type Customer {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  email: String!
}

interface CustomerErrorInterface {
  message: String!
}

type MissingCustomerEmailError implements CustomerErrorInterface {
  id: ID!
}

union CustomerResult = Customer | CustomerErrorInterface

type Query {
  getCustomers: [CustomerResult!]!
}
```

Then, on the client side, your query would look something like this:

```
query getCustomers() {
  __typename
  ... on Customer {
    id
    name
    email
  }
  ... on CustomerErrorInterface {
    message
  }
  ... on MissingCustomerEmailError {
    id
  }
}
```

This allows you to maintain type safety and avoid nulling things that shouldn't be nullable, while still reporting meaningful results (both successes and error types) that are associated with the data you do have.  Using an error interface rather than a concrete error type in the union allows you to leave the option for reporting new types of errors in the future in a backward-compatible way.

The difference between this and the "default" GQL way of error handling (with the top-level `errors` output) is that reporting the error in an interface allows still giving meaningful reference data (like the `id` field) in easy locations rather than needing to parse error messages, and different types of errors can provide different reference data as appropriate.  Error interface type handling also better fits with regular GraphQL output type patterns (in my opinion) rather than needing to switch on an enum to know how to handle different types of errors.

Allowing null in the output list may accomplish something similar in this particular case, but it makes it impossible to know *which* piece of data has an error, especially if the data in question does not correspond directly to a user-supplied input that can be found through the path provided by traditional error handling.